# Symbolic link with option

Tags: symlink, options, ln

Is it possible to create a symbolic link to an executable that executes it with a certain option/argument?

I know a workaround would be to create a bash script in one of the PATH directories but can I achieve it somehow with a symbolic link?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers, in my case an alias wouldn't do the job because i'm looking for a way to start matlab from dmenu and at least on arch matlab is only invokable from a terminal at first. Since dmenu does not consider aliases it wouldn't work .. i should have made my problem more clear.

Comment: If the executable is one which *you are compiling*, then you can do this, and it is in fact a common practice.  By having multiple links (hard *or* soft) to an executable, and basing the behaviour on the value of `$0`, you get the effect you desire (where "which you are compiling" means writing code and compiling, not simply installing a standard package with `./configure ; make`).

Comment: very interesting @user4556274 this is good to know ! I'm trying to invoke matlab with -desktop automatically when i invoke matlab. But i can't compile matlab myself :) so not possible in my case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, a symbolic link is a type of file that references the path of another file.

Now, if you do:

```
ln -s /bin/cat foo
```

And invoke `foo` as:

```
$ ./foo -A /proc/self/cmdline
./foo^@-A^@/proc/self/cmdline^@
```

You'll notice that the *first* argument that `cat`/`foo` received was `./foo` and not `cat`. So, in a way, through that symlink, we've had `cat` receive a different *first* argument. That's probably not what you had in mind for your *first* argument though.

Using a shell script wrapper is the typical way to address it. You don't need to use `bash` for that though. Your system's standard `sh` will be more than enough for that:

```
#! /bin/sh -
exec /path/to/my/executable --extra-option "$@"
```

Other options include defining an `alias` or function in your `~/.bashrc`/`~/.zshrc`... for it

Comment: nice, i guess "$@" will pass on the args i call the script with.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you want let's say for example call `script.sh` and make it run `script.sh arg1`, so you can do that with alias, its like `grep` in linux, actually when you call it in ubuntu you calling grep --color=auto.

To do that create an alias, and put it in the right file depending on you distribution, for example in ubuntu you can put it in `~/.bashrc` file

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
alias script.sh='script.sh arg1'
```

for more info: http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/set-command-aliases-linuxubuntudebian/